# How to create a dynamic layout inside a linear layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Please Help me with this! Um stucked!

```
   LinearLayout rR;

  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params5 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                ((int) ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int)      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

   TextView[] tv5 = new TextView[value1];
    rR.addView(tv5[i]);}
```

This works fine but inside this rR layout I need to create another layout Dynamically!

Comment: Are you trying to add one TextView to the LinearLayout or multiple TextViews? You can use TextView tv5=new TextView(context);   tv5.setText("your text");  rR.addView(tv5);

Comment: I have to add images , textviews and swiches and all dynamically! Simply the layout cannot be aligned neatly! so i was thinking to have a dynamic layout to get them all at once

Comment: Firstly you will need an orientation for your linear layout(horizontal or vertical) . Then for every element you want to add you will need to add a 'addView' statement. There's no way to batch add views. Also if your view doesn't contain anything there will only be a blank space in its place. For example a TextView without text will just look like it's not there.

Comment: ok thnx a lot ! I'll try that!

Answer (score 2):

the link show how to create dynamically layout in android !! [click here](http://androidexample.com/Dynamically_Create_View_Elements__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=115&aaid=137)

Comment: Thanx a lot I'll refer this!

Comment: link only answer are not preferred as the link might get broken in the future